# Openstack/devstack Installation - The conflict is caused by: oslo-vmware 3.9.1 depends on suds-jurko>=0.6

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am trying to install devstack on Ubuntu 18.04, using the guide in https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/.

Installation fails with the error,

```
ERROR: Cannot install cinder because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    oslo-vmware 3.9.1 depends on suds-jurko>=0.6
    The user requested (constraint) suds-jurko===0.6

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I have 2 python versions on the machine

```
stack@stack:~/devstack$ which python
/usr/bin/python
stack@stack:~/devstack$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Am I missing something here?

Best Regards,

J

Comment: Maybe you should use `venv`(python virtual environment what you need) to deploy your `openstack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install setuptools 57.5.0

```
vim /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt
```

like this:

```
#setuptools===58.2.0
setuptools===57.5.0
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `suds-jurko` is incompatible with the setuptools 58.0. You would need to downgrade to setuptools 57.5.0, e.g. `pip install setuptools==57.5.0`, but it's possible that devstack will upgrade it again.

The real solution is a set of upstream patches that are already in the works to fix this, but isn't merged yet (as of this post).
https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/oslo.vmware/+/813377